# accessing master page in subfolder structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have hosted my web app in IIS version 10, Windows 10 OS. My web app running perfect from visual studio.

When I host my app in IIS and browse my web form in location "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WATER\view\User\AddCustomer.aspx" I am getting error :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The file '/view/MasterPage/AdminMaster.master.cs' does not exist.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AdminMaster.master.cs" Inherits="AdminMaster" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html>

Source File: /view/MasterPage/AdminMaster.master    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4075.0
```

Path of Master page file directory is :: "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WATER\view\MasterPage"

Master page path in this web form AddCustomer.aspx is::

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/view/MasterPage/AdminMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddCustomer.aspx.cs" Inherits="DENTAL.view.User.AddCustomer" %>
```

I tried changing the path of the master page as ::

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AdminMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddCustomer.aspx.cs" Inherits="DENTAL.view.User.AddCustomer" %>
```

then again

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/AdminMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddCustomer.aspx.cs" Inherits="DENTAL.view.User.AddCustomer" %>
```

but no success. I can not browse any of the webform from other directories too, everywhere getting the same error.

Please see the image of directory structure of my app in IIS. Please help. Thank You!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Current Master page path is ~/MasterPage/AdminMaster.master as ~ denote root folder(wwwroot), so application is not getting master page.

Master page is located at ~/WATER/view/MasterPage/AdminMaster.master. so update master page reference in referred page(addcustomer.aspx) as :

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/WATER/view/MasterPage/AdminMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddCustomer.aspx.cs" Inherits="DENTAL.view.User.AddCustomer" %>
```